# Reducing too many if statements

Tags: php, laravel, if-statement, conditional-statements

So I have this one input field which I use to search my database. I want to be able to simply search for a `day`, a `day` + `month` or a `day` + `month` + `year`, like so:

18 // day only
18-1 // day + month
18-1-2018 // day + month + year

What I first need to do, is split the results using explode:

```
$date = explode("-", $this->string); // $this->string is set in the constructor
```

Which will give me an array of either 1, 2 or 3 results (we will assume the input is correct).

The problem is that I have just way too many `if/else` statements, in both my methods:

**search():**

```
public function search()
{
    $date = explode("-", $this->string);

    if (array_key_exists(2, $date))
    {
        if (!is_numeric($date[0]) || !is_numeric($date[1]) || !is_numeric($date[2]))
        {
            return false;
        }

        return $this->dateCheck($date[0], $date[1], $date[2]);
    }

    if (array_key_exists(1, $date))
    {
        if (!is_numeric($date[0]) || !is_numeric($date[1]))
        {
            return false;
        }

        return $this->dateCheck($date[0], $date[1]);
    }

    if (array_key_exists(0, $date))
    {
        if (!is_numeric($date[0]))
        {
            return false;
        }

        return $this->dateCheck($date[0]);
    }

    return false;
}
```

**dateCheck():**

```
private function dateCheck($day = null, $month = null, $year = null)
{
    if ($year == null)
    {
        $year = Carbon::now()->format('Y');
    }

    if ($month == null)
    {
        $month = Carbon::now()->format('m');
    }

    if ($day == null)
    {
        $day = Carbon::now()->format('d');
    }

    return (bool) checkdate($month, $day, $year);
}
```

My question is, would anyone have any better solution to reduce any amount of `if/else` statements?

PS. If returned false anywhere, there will be a redirect back to the input page with a flash message stating there were no results.

Comment: Try posting it [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead, especially if you only need optimization

Comment: where your db query for searching??

Comment: Thanks, posted it there :) Should I delete this one here or leave it up?

Comment: The db query is not important for this question so I left it all out

Comment: it could be as there is a number of query method available to query date type data in laravel query builder and eloquent, may be those could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're on PHP >= 5.6, you can use the splat operator (`...`), also known as argument unpacking. You can read about in the [PHP manual here](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php).

The splat operator will take the elements in the array and pass them in as individual arguments.

```
public function search()
{
    $date = explode("-", $this->string);

    // If any items are not numeric, this will evaluate to false.
    $numeric = array_reduce($date, function ($carry, $item) {
        return $carry && is_numeric($item);
    }, true);

    if (empty($date) || !$numeric) {
        return false;
    }

    return $this->dateCheck(...$date);
}
```

If you're not on PHP 5.6 yet, your last lines will need to be a little different. You can use the `call_user_func_array()` function, which calls the function with the array items as parameters.

```
return call_user_func_array([$this, 'datecheck'], $date);
```

Or, you can design the array so that the indexes will always exist:

```
$date = array_replace([null, null, null], $date);

return $this->dateCheck($date[0], $date[1], $date[2]);
```

You can also use the ternary shortcut operator (`?:`) to reduce your `dateCheck` function to something like this:

```
private function dateCheck($day = null, $month = null, $year = null)
{
    return (bool) checkdate(
        $month ?: Carbon::now()->format('m'),
        $day ?: Carbon::now()->format('d'),
        $year ?: Carbon::now()->format('Y')
    );
}
```

This basically says that if the variable is false-y (null, 0, '', false, etc), replace it with the Carbon output. If you want to be strict on the null check, and you're on PHP 7, you could use the null coalesce operator (`??`) instead of the ternary shortcut operator. Then the Carbon value would only be used if the variable was `null`.

Comment: Some great answers here, but gonna have to go with this one, well explained (just like the answer from @OptimusCrime) but I like some of the stuff you posted here a little better

Comment: There is `call_user_func_array too` too to use an array to fill the parameters in a function call

Comment: @Eineki Absolutely. Thanks for reminding me. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Also thanks for that splat operator, some good things to learn here :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$date = explode('-', $x);
$date = array_replace([date('d'), date('m'), date('Y')], $date);
```

[**emo**](https://eval.in/937162)

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your code a lot. The `dateCheck` function can not be reduced that much in logic, but we can write it somewhat prettier:

```
$year = $year === null ? Carbon::now()->format('Y') : $year;
$month = $month === null ? Carbon::now()->format('m') : $month;
$day = $day === null ? Carbon::now()->format('d') : $day;
return (bool) checkdate($month, $day, $year);
```

The `search` function can use an utility function that reduces the amount of overhead necessary to determine if a date is valid. Something like this:

```
$date = explode("-", $this->string);
if (count($date) === 3 and static::isValidDate($date)) {
    return $this->dateCheck($date[0], $date[1], $date[2]);
}
if (count($date) === 2 and static::isValidDate($date)) {
    return $this->dateCheck($date[0], $date[1]);
}
if (count($date) === 1 and static::isValidDate($date)) {
    return $this->dateCheck($date[0]);
}
return false;
```

And finally, the new (static) method `isValidDate`:

```
private static function isValidDate(array $date) {
    foreach ($date as $field) {
        if (!is_numeric($field)) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

---

You can also rewrite the coder to be even simpler, reusing the same `isValidDate` method, and changing the `search` function to:

```
$date = explode("-", $this->string);
if (static::isValidDate($date)) {
    return $this->dateCheck($date);
}
return false;
```

And the `dateCheck` to (note that the arguments for this function now is a single `date` variable that is an array):

```
$year = !isset($date[0]) ? Carbon::now()->format('Y') : $date[0];
$month = !isset($date[1]) ? Carbon::now()->format('m') : $date[1];
$day = !isset($date[2]) ? Carbon::now()->format('d') : $date[2];
return (bool) checkdate($month, $day, $year);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your search function you can just convert the date string into an array

```
    $date = explode("-", $this->string);
```

filter out the non numeric values (shouldn't be there)

```
    $valid = array_filter($date, 'is_numeric');
```

and check if are all valid Il valid (short circuit the evaluaton) return the result of the real computation

```
    return (count($date) === count($valid)) && 
            call_user_func_array(array($this, 'dateCheck'), $valid);    

public function search()
{
    $date = explode("-", $this->string);
    $valid = array_filter($date, 'is_numeric');
    return (count($date) === count($valid)) && 
            call_user_func_array(array($this, 'dateCheck'), $valid);    
}
```

for the datecheck function: we will just add the default value at the end of the parameters passed and just use first three values, no need of ifs or ternary operation.

```
private function dateCheck($day = null, $month = null, $year = null)
{
    $date = array_filter(func_get_args(), 'is_int');
    array_push($date, Carbon::now()->format('m'), Carbon::now()->format('Y');
    list($day, $month, $year) = array_slice($date, 0,3);
    return (bool) checkdate($month, $day, $year);
}
```